# Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Boa noite, estou com um probleminha que não consigo resolver. Usei um adapter para fazer uma lista de itens, porem o "item 1" está por baixo da barra ( ira entender olhando pra foto ). Mas não sei como resolver. Irei passar o codigo do meu navigation.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Navigation Drawer:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

NavigationView navigationView = null;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private static final int TELA_SOBRE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Set the fragment initially
    MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction1 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction1.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    transaction1.commit();


    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            chamarDialog();
        }
    });


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    //How to change elements in the header programatically
    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    TextView emailText = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.email);
    emailText.setText("newemail@email.com");

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Classe do adapter:

```
public class AcessFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
private ListView lista;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_acess, container, false);

    lista = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lista);
    String[] listaOpcoes = {"item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1, listaOpcoes);
    // adapter.clear(); Limpar adapter
    // adapter.addAll(listaOpcoes); Adiciona vários
    // adapter.add("Nova String"); Adiciona uma String

    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //String itemSelecionado = (String) this.lista.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Item selecionado: " + itemSelecionado, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (position == 0) {

    } else if (position == 1) {

    } else if (position == 2) {

    } else if (position == 3) {


    }


}
```

xml do adapter:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lista"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
```

activity_xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

xml app_bar_main

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="br.com.projeto.caminhossembarreiras.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_location" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Você pode adicionar o arquivo `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: Claro, adicionado!

Comment: Não ficou muito claro esses dois layouts pra mim, poderia incluir o xml do `app_bar_main`? Não consigo ver como esta a hierarquia da tela, isso é, a ligação da toolbar/appbar com o `ListView`.

Comment: Aparentemente está incompleto! Onde o `fragment_container` que o `MainFragment` está sendo inflado? Acredito que o seu problema esteja na hierarquia do seu `activity_main.xml`

Comment: @Wakim adicionado, obrigado por tentar ajudar!

Comment: Acho que falta adicionar `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` no seu `FrameLayout` logo abaixo do `AppBarLayout`.

Answer (score 2):

O problema acontece por que estas usando um layout relativo com a ListView dentro, nesse caso a lista irá começar do topo.

Como Você tem apenas uma lista dentro do layout, uma forma simples de resolver é trocar o seu RelativeLayout por um LinearLayout, e tudo ficará certo.

```
<LinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
      android:id="@+id/lista"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Mudei e continuou a mesma coisa!

Answer (score 1):

Se você trocar `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` por um `RelativeLayout`. 
Você pode utilizar a tag `android:layout_below="@id/id_app_bar"` (vai precisar criar um id pro include do app_bar).

Outra maneira, mas não sei se irá funcionar é:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/nav_view"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    />
```

Nesse caso utilizei o layout_above, pois seu xml do app_bar está definido como layout relativo.